# MacOS 10.15.4 APFS is overwriting case-sensitive files

Tags: macos, overwrite, apfs

I created a APFS volume on my MacOS 10.15.4 hard drive. diskutil info confirms it is a case-sensitive APFS.

When I untar a Linux-generated archive that contains case-sensitive files, similarly named files that differ only by case (such as File.h and file.h) are being overwritten. I can confirm via tar tfv that the case-senstive files are indeed present in the archive.

However, when I manually create a small test archive with mixed-case files of similar names, it archives and unarchives fine preserving the case-sensitive names.

Why are files being over-written, and is there a work around?

Comment: how are you un-tarring?

Comment: The archive is in .tgz format, and it is unarchived automatically within a larger Python package using default tar xf.  Ideally, it should be tar xfz, but separate tests confirm tar xf works on my manual test cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git (MacOS) case sensitive overwrite issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575463/git-macos-case-sensitive-overwrite-issues)

Comment: Mac file systems are case-sensitive by default... Work-arounds: create a new "container" (partition); do this work in a VM; do this work in a Docker container; extract files one at a time `tar xf arch.tgz path/to/File.h`