# Case-sensitive path collisions on case-insensitive file system when I do git clone

Tags: git, macos, windows-10, ntfs, apfs

when I git clone the repository the following warning appears:

```
...
warning: the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree:

  'components/User/index.js'
  'components/user/index.js'
```

I've been reading and it may be a windows problem since case sensitive is not enabled in the folder paths. I also tried with `git config --global core.ignorecase false` but it keeps failing.

This problem is faced with all case-insensitive file systems, i.e Windows 10(NTFS) and macOS(APFS).

Does anyone also see this problem?

Comment: Your filesystem is probably case insensitive, so it does not have any way of distinguishing those two file names/paths. To your file system, `abc` and `abC` must refer to exactly the same file. Git, which tracks files in a case-sensitive way, is warning you that the repository you are cloning wants to treat `abc` and `abC` as different files, yet your filesystem is unable to represent that. Try using a case sensitive FS. Or investigate whether the colliding files are actually meant to hold different contents.

Comment: @Juan you never accepted an answer. None of them are correct?

Comment: I know Juan probably isn't using GitHub, or he'd have probably found this solution himself, but, just because this is such a _massive_ pain to solve on macOS, I want to point out to any future readers that if you happen to have the repo on GitHub, you can use GitHub's feature for removing files, to delete one of the copies.

Answer (score 48):

### Definitions

- **case-sensitive** filesystem: treats `john.jpg` and `JOHN.jpg` as *two different files* and this is allowed.
- **case-insensitive** filesystem: treats `john.jpg` and `JOHN.jpg` as *one and the same file* which is **not** allowed.

### Problem

```
'components/User/index.js'
'components/user/index.js'
```

The problem here is that `User` and `user` are not allowed to co-exist at the same time inside the `components` directory on a case-insensitive filesystem (which is [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) if you're using Windows 10).

### Solution for windows OS

If you have recently cloned the repo and have not done any work on it yet, I recommend that you start over. So remove the clone, then enable case-sensitivity for the directory you intend to clone your repo in, and then clone it anew. The benefit of doing this ahead of the cloning process is that all directories that are created as part of the cloning process by git will be case-sensitive and git will no longer give this warning. Plus, it enables you to clean up the mess.

1. Open a command prompt as an administrator.
2. Go to the directory where you intend to clone your repo. In this example I will use `C:\Users\Juan\Desktop`. You don't have to `cd` to this directory to do the next step, just know what your target directory is.
3. Enable case-sensitivity for the target directory. Command: `fsutil.exe file SetCaseSensitiveInfo "C:\Users\Juan\Desktop" enable`
4. Clone your repo. In this example I will use `https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git`. Command: `git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git`
5. (optional): Remove or rename conflicting files and folders if they are the same. You need to verify this by comparing them. To remove, use `git rm` and to move or copy, use `git mv`.
6. (optional): Commit and push up your changes to the upstream repo if you have write permission (and possibly after discussing the problem with the rest of the team).
7. (optional): Disable case-sensitivity. Command: `fsutil.exe file SetCaseSensitiveInfo "C:\Users\Juan\Desktop" disable`

Now you can go back to working on the project.

Source: [Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-ntfs-treat-folders-case-sensitive-windows-10)

### Solution for macOS

On macOS, you will have to reformat volume as case-insensitive/sensitive or make a new volume altogether. [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64745655/7338187)

### Reflection

You probably ran into this problem because you cloned a repo that was created on a computer that runs Linux or Mac, perhaps it was created by someone else and not you personally. The lesson here is to always be consistent with the way you name things, and this applies to everyone involved in a project. This is one example of what can happen otherwise.

Comment: Does not worked on windows

Comment: @SantanuBiswas pls eleborate on what steps did not work for you. For me, this answer perfectly solved my problem on Windows

Comment: On my windows with NTFS disk I get: "Error:  The request is not supported."

Comment: Ah, fixed by adding Windows Subsystem for Linux : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/issues/977

Comment: fix for termux, on android: use only internal storage. no way around it!

Answer (score 5):

The process of changing your entire file system on macOS is very time-consuming and risky. One can utilize Disk Images as explained [here](https://www.geekyhacker.com/2021/08/04/fix-case-sensitive-paths-on-a-case-insensitive-filesystem-on-macos/) to create virtual containers with specific case-sensitive (i.e., "Journaled") file systems:

- Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+ - Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)
- Journaled HFS+ - Mac OS Extended (Journaled)

If one likes to use terminal:

- Create an image using `hdiutil create -type SPARSE -fs 'Case-sensitive APFS' -volname <volumeName> <fileName>`.
- The `hdiutil attach <fileName>.sparseimage` command, mounts the image into `/Volumes/<volumeName>` which you can `cd` into.
- When you are done just unmount the image with `diskutil unmount /Volumes/<volumeName>`.

You may find more info [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/433675/208759).

Answer (score 5):

My solution to this issue (on Windows) was to:

1. Copy the file and save it outside the repo.
2. Delete the file in the repo. This has the effect of showing both files deleted in the git status.
3. Commit the deletion and push
4. Re-add the file to the repo, commit and push

After this my repo was showing as up to date with nothing to commit.

Comment: reformat volume seems a bit overkill of a solution, this worked in my case like a charm

Comment: Worked perfectly fine for change a single file that drove me crazy...

Comment: By the way, you do not need to `push` after deleting the two files.

Answer (score 3):

Use Windows 10's ability to enable **case sensitivity on a per-directory basis**.

Also, **Windows Subsystem for Linux** let's you mount Windows folders as case sensitive.

For more information:

[How to Enable Case Sensitive File and Folder Names on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/)

[Per-directory case sensitivity and WSL | Windows Command Line](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/)

Comment: In other words, on a admin PowerShell execute: `fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo "C:\my folder" enable`

Comment: I enabled this, but when I deleted the 'bad' folder, Windows proceeds to delete the 'good' folder. Is there a way to make delete case sensitive?

Comment: @RedRidingHood to get out of the weird hole you are in, you'll have to play some tricks. Once you're out, going forward you'll be fine. Since you didn't supply much detail, i can only guess, so "tricks" along the lines of: make a backup copy of the good folder. Then let Windows delete the good folder, then delete the bad folder, then put your backup of the good one back in place.

Comment: the solution doesnot work