# git shows changes to one file as 2 seperate modifications (same path but one capitalized)

Tags: git

I changed one file in our repository and it shows the following on git status:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   Workflow/Workflow/WorkflowBuilders/WorkflowBuilder.cs
        modified:   workflow/Workflow/WorkflowBuilders/WorkflowBuilder.cs
```

This is the reason for a lot of issues we face currently e.g. one of the files is shown as deleted but it still exists when changing branches. As well as duplicate file changes on commit (see above). This happens with all files / folders under the first W(w)orkflow folder

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you on W/windows?

Comment: yes I am on Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Yep, well, the problem with Windows and case has been covered here soooo many times... Please search.

Comment: I've found one post with the same issue but there is no accepted answer.

Comment: I did these steps and they worked so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64466310/10585750

Comment: The fix doesn't work. The bug reintroduces itself over and over whenever an old branch is checkedout once, then all branches have this issue! The only fix would be to create a complete new git repository...